# How to switch the X-axis by the Y-axis in matplotlib? (specific case)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I don't know how to switch the X-axis (directors) to be in the Y-axis in this case. (see the image to determine what I mean)

[image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=[14.70, 8.27])

oi = imdb.groupby(['director'])["revenue_adj"].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
oi.plot(x="director",kind="bar");

plt.xlabel("Director",fontsize=18);
plt.ylabel("Total Revenue",fontsize=18);
plt.title("Top 10 directors by total revenue for the movies they directed",fontsize=21);
```

Comment: `oi.plot(x="director",kind="barh")`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas Nice! You can write your comment as an answer so OP can accept it and close the question

Comment: @DerekO Thanks mate but Some question don't need an answer they just need a comment **:)**